# Overring Material-UI style with makeStyles

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am working on a small portfolio website, I've added an avatar, and trying to override it's style with makeStyles class, tho the Mui avatar root is overriding my class,

is this possible to do without the use of !important ?

```
export const HomePage = () => {
    const classes = useStyles()
    return (
        <Grid container justifyContent="center">
            <Avatar className={classes.headerAvatar} src={avatar} alt="" />
        </Grid>
    )
}


export const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
headerAvatar: {
        width: theme.spacing(13),
        height: theme.spacing(13),
        margin: theme.spacing(1)
    },
}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://v4.mui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes), you can override the css style of the `root` class using the `classes` prop, like:

```
export const HomePage = () => {
    const classes = useStyles()
    return (
        <Grid container justifyContent="center">
            <Avatar classes={classes} src={avatar} alt="" />
        </Grid>
    )
}


export const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
        width: theme.spacing(13),
        height: theme.spacing(13),
        margin: theme.spacing(1)
    },
}))
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that before but seems apparently my mistake was adding a space after the & for example this work now -  '&.MuiAvatar-root': {
   width: theme.spacing(13),
   height: theme.spacing(13),
   margin: '0.5rem auto',
  },

Comment: You don't really need to use the `Global class`, if you use `classes` instead of `className` you can use the `Rule name` like in my example.